# __flash__addCallback problem - Flash Player 9.0.47

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I'm having an issue with:

`__flash`__addCallback(variable, "sendData");

When trying to interact with a movie via javascript, where 'variable' is undefined - but only in flash versions less than 9.0.115, in my case the problem presents itself with version 9.0.47 - tested in IE.

I've searched and have found a few posts regarding this bug, but ultimately I can find little else on the subject apart from the fact that it is fixed in flash player 9.0.115 and up.

Whilst I have proven that to be the case, I need to know if I can fix this somehow for users that do have v9 earlier players (which I have no control over) without forcing them to have 9.0.115+, or if this is a bug that I have to 'live' with if users happen to have the early affected versions.

Help? :/

Comment: Doesn't at all solve your problem, but FP 9.0.47 is now over 3 years old, its install base is likely quite small as people who are/were capable of upgrading to FP9, continue to upgrade, and those occupying FP8 land are unable to upgrade for other reasons. I'll post an answer if I can find anything useful in a bit.

Comment: This is fair enough really, I just don't like the idea of anyone at all suffering prom this problem on our site as it's a pretty important bit of functionality that breaks! But - I may just have to live with it on this basis.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to discern additional information about the error if it is coming from JavaScript, since I believe Flash Player's dynamically injected JS is the source of the problem, by setting ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions to true before adding callbacks (and wrapping the addCallback function in try/catch).

Granted, marshallExceptions is not explicitly defined as capable of enabling the passing of JavaScript exceptions via the addCallback function, it may do...something.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll investigate!